# Correct way to Inject CDI Contextual beans into existing Non-contextual bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-6, destroy

The below is the code I use to inject CDI contextual beans into a Non-contextual object.

```
    // My controller is Non-contextual bean
    public class MyController extends Controller {

        @Inject
        ModelBinder modelBinder;

        @Inject
        ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

        private CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext;

        public void setCreationalContext(CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext) {
            this.creationalContext = creationalContext;
        }

        public CreationalContext<Controller> getCreationalContext() {
            return creationalContext;
        }

        // Other fields
    }
```

**Code to Initialize MyController**

```
    // Create Non-contextual bean
    MyController controller = new MyController();

    AnnotatedType<?> at = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(controller.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<Controller> it = (InjectionTarget<Controller>)beanManager.createInjectionTarget(at);

    CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

    // Perform inject
    it.inject(controller, creationalContext);

    // Store creationalContext related
    controller.setCreationalContext(creationalContext);
```

**Code to Destroy MyController**

```
    // controller is instance of MyController
    AnnotatedType<?> at = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(controller.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<Controller> it = (InjectionTarget<Controller>)beanManager.createInjectionTarget(at);

    it.dispose(controller);

    controller.getCreationalContext().release();
```

**Today, My team leader discussed with me and he said: Because ModelBinder, ApplicationConfig are CDI Application scope beans so I don't have to write code destroy Controller and the code he suggested like below:**

```
    // New MyController
    public class MyController extends Controller {

        @Inject
        ModelBinder modelBinder;

        @Inject
        ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

        // Do not need to store creationalContext
        //private CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext;

        //public void setCreationalContext(CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext) {
        //  this.creationalContext = creationalContext;
        //}

        //public CreationalContext<Controller> getCreationalContext() {
        //  return creationalContext;
        //}

        // Other fields
    }
```

**New Code to Initialize MyController**

```
    // Create Non-contextual bean
    MyController controller = new MyController();

    AnnotatedType<?> at = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(controller.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<Controller> it = (InjectionTarget<Controller>)beanManager.createInjectionTarget(at);

    CreationalContext<Controller> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

    // Perform inject
    it.inject(controller, creationalContext);

    // Do not need to store creationalContext related
    // controller.setCreationalContext(creationalContext);
```

**New Code to Destroy MyController**

```
    // No need code to destroy the controller
```

**Anyone has any ideas?** Thank you very much!

Comment: I have to ask, why do you even instantiate the controller yourself? Why not use the CDI container to get references to it?

Answer (score 4):

Since CDI 1.1, the `Unmanaged` helper class is provided to ease working with non-contextual instances, so that you can write:

```
Unmanaged<MyController> unmanaged = new Unmanaged<MyController>(MyController.class);
UnmanagedInstance<MyController> instance = unmanaged.newInstance();
MyController controller  = instance.produce().inject().postConstruct().get();
... // Use the controller instance
instance.preDestroy().dispose();
```

That version uses CDI.current() to retrieve the `BeanManager` though you can provide it if required:

```
Unmanaged<MyController> unmanaged = new Unmanaged<MyController>(beanManager, MyController.class);
```

More information can be found in the CDI specification in [obtaining non-contextual instance](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bm_obtain_unmanaged_instance).

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question/problem here is why do you need to instantiate your controller instead of getting a managed reference?

You can use a `@Dependent` scoped bean to achieve the same thing as `Unmanaged` is tackling.  You can even use a factory pattern to delegate some of the work away.  Support you have this injection point:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<MyController> myControllerProvider;
```

in your business method, when you need the reference, you can do

```
MyController controller = myControllerProvider.get();
```

Which will give you a managed reference.  I did however notice you were using a static class - this implies its not a top level class.  CDI would require it as a top level class.

Comment: I just updated. Remove static keyword. Another reason I create Controller by myself is Controller instance created in a Method so its lifecycle is the method lifecycle.